# How to ensure that the best model is being pushed to Hugging Face Hub when using `load_best_model_at_end=True` in the Trainer API?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I am fine-tuning a BERT model from Hugging Face on a token classification task.

Here are my training arguments:

```py
args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="bert-finetuned-ner",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=5,
    metric_for_best_model="f1", # load model with highest F1 score
    greater_is_better=True, # load model with highest F1 score
    load_best_model_at_end=True, # load model with highest F1 score
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    num_train_epochs=50, # train for 50 epochs max; using EarlyStoppingCallback in the Trainer
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_steps=10,
    logging_strategy="epoch",
    push_to_hub=True
)
```

And my `Trainer` class:

```py
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["test"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    callbacks=[EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)],
)
```

Finally, I train the model and push it to the Hugging Face Hub:

```py
trainer.train()

trainer.push_to_hub()
```

The model trains for 10 epochs and then stops due to the `EarlyStoppingCallback`. **The model has the best F1 score on epoch 7.** Nonetheless, the auto-generated model card on Hugging Face Hub is specifying **the metrics on epoch 10** (i.e. the last epoch) - which obviously have a worse F1 score than on epoch 7.

This causes confusion because I am not sure if the model checkpoints that were pushed to the Hub are the checkpoints from epoch 7, or the checkpoints from epoch 10. Since I specified `load_best_model_at_end=True` in my TrainingArguments, I expected the model card to show the metrics from epoch 7.

Is there a way to figure out whether the model that was pushed to the Hub is the one with the best metrics (7th epoch) or the one from the 10th epoch?

I tried reading the HF Transformers and Hub documentation, but I didn't find anything related to this issue.

Comment: hey got the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: You can re-download the uploaded model from huggingface and checksum both downloaded pytorch_model.bin and ensured the best model's pytorch_model.bin. Then, compare them.